# is there any different solution for different buildings different behaviours

Tags: c++, software-engineering, oop, polymorphism

I'm trying to make different behaviours for workers of different buildings, let's say an agricultural worker would need to sow wheat seed and collect the wheat grain when it's grown. let's call that `Behaviour0`

For carpentry a worker would get wood and make arrows.

I have 2 different behaviours and I would like to implement them all in the simplest way possible.

```
 class agricultural{
     Workr Work
     void Working(Work W){
         Behaviour1();
     }
 }
 class Carpentry{
     Workr Work
     void Working(Work W){
         Behaviour2();
     }
 }
 template <tipename T> class BuildWork{
     T BW
     Work(){
         BW.Working();
     }
 }
```

I tried doing it with template so the behaviour would be inside `agricultural` and `carpentry` but problem occurred when I tried to declare template as only 1 can be inside it and getting it with ifs would make it the same as a non-templated version.

```
 class Workr{
     // here I would need to make it only for 1 is possible
     BuildWork <agricultural> BW
 }
```

So is this how I should use it?

The next thing occurred to me is this

```
 class Building{
     bool beh[2];
     void Work(Workr W){
         if beh[0]{
             if (beh[1]){
                 behaviour0(Workr W);
             }
             else{
                 behaviour1(Workr W);
             }
         }
         else{
             if (beh[1]){
                 behaviour2(Workr W);
             }
             else{
                  behaviour3(Workr W);
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

The last code is workable but I wonder if there is a better solution for this? here I can just change the bits in the `beh[ ]` and it's working

Each building has different behaviours and each worker in that specific building has same behaviour. Specific behaviour is always in the same building type.

Comment: You might want to revisit this question and describe what you're trying to achieve, the issue you have, and the solution you though about before introducing the code you use.

Comment: So you want that in a specific building, you get any type of "worker" which would each have their own behaviour?

Comment: each building has different behaviours and each worker in that specific building has same behaviour

Comment: Can a behaviour be present in different building types, or a specific behaviour is always in the same building type?

Comment: Specific behaviour is allways in same building type

Comment: I have reopen the question. Please edit it and add everything you need in it, including what you described. Also, know that there are some [online tools](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/) to write c++ code that will at least give you the possibility to write code that compiles, which would remove some ambiguities that we have here currently.

Comment: that code makes me wander and I don't quite understand it - afaik for loop has 2 ; but here it has only 1 :

Comment: make answer and I'll accept your question and I'll look deep in to that code when I'll be on my computer atm I'm on hospitals computer and I can only program on sheets of paper with pencil

Comment: The link I added is to an online code editor and compiler. When you launch the default page, it will post a code sample; it's not something I wrote myself. The idea here is that you take the code you wrote in the question and make sure it has no syntax errors. Right now, the code you wrote lacks some `;` characters, and is confusing. Please edit the question so that it contains all the details you posted as comments.